# Analytics : list all routes from landing pages to money page

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I would like to be able to create a report listing all routes from landing pages to the money page, with number of visitors, bounce rate and trafic source.

Example : "my keywords" -> page A (90 visitors, 20% bounce rate) -> page X (72v, 45% br) -> money page

I am willing to use any analytics solution (free or paid). Google analytics would be simpler, but i can't find how to do that with it.

I know analytics solutions have the raw data allowing this kind of report, but if a tool already exist, i'd rather use it.

I'm taking any insight, any idea. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can't you do that with Google Analytics Content Flow?

Comment: i should be able to :/ the report merges routes at each nodes. you can't tell where they come from and where they're going. example : they come from pages A and B, through page C to pages D and E. There's no simple way to tell if the user coming from A is ending in E.